# conversion operator as standalone function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, conversion-operator

Why does C++ require that user-defined conversion operator can only be non-static member?
Why is it not allowed to use standalone functions as for other unary operators?
Something like this:

```
operator bool (const std::string& s) { return !s.empty(); }
```

Comment: This would be handy to convert between `std::string` and `QString`, which is acid in the face of my code's readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The one reason I can think of is to prevent implicit conversions being applied to the thing being cast. In your example, if you said:

```
 bool( "foo" );
```

then "foo" would be implicitly converted to a string, which would then have the explicit bool  conversion you provided applied to it.

This is not possible if the bool operator is a member function, as implicit conversions are not applied to `*this`. This greatly reduces the possibilities for ambiguity - ambiguities normally being seen as a "bad thing".

Comment: I don't understand your argument.
The example you gave is not an implicit conversion.
On the other hand the main reason for defining a conversion operator is to use implicit conversion.

Comment: @shura Yes it is. "foo" is being implicitly converted to  a string, which is then explicitly converted to a bool. I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: To further explain the ambiguities, this could be treated as a conversion from pointer to `bool` though it would always result in `true` then.

Comment: Wouldn't this example, if it worked, take two user-defined conversions? And don't we ever get only one?

Comment: @sbi That's true - I think D.Shawley's example is a better one.

Comment: But why is bool( "foo" ) == false a problem? This is exactly what the explicit conversion operator defined in the question means (if worked).

Comment: There is a `explicit` keyword in **C++**.

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the conversion operator within the class you give the author of the class control of how it could be converted (It prevents users from creating **implicit** conversions). As an implementer I would consider this an advantage, as [implicit conversions does have its issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160432/are-implicit-conversions-good-or-bad-in-modern-c)

There is a difference being able to pass one object as another, and having it to go through a conversion function. The former communicates that the object is of a given type, while the latter shows new readers that there is a difference between the two types and that a conversion is necessary.

Comment: It doesn't give any extra control. I can (and probably should) simply write  a ToBool() function to do the conversion.

Comment: It does too :) Implicit conversion is something quite different than a ToBool(). If I could I would make std::string implicit convertible to a char*, but fortunately Stroustrup et al. knew better.

Answer (score -2):

Implicit user-defined conversions are frowned upon anyway. Don't use them. Just pretend that they aren't there. Let alone thinking about newer ways to introduce them.

Anyway, I guess they aren't there because the way they are they can do enough unexpected things. Including a new header which introduces such a conversion for a class defined somewhere else might lead to even more confusing errors.

Comment: So when C++0x allows using `explicit` with cast operators, does your argument still hold?  I could envision some usefulness to freestanding cast operators that can be used only with `static_cast`.

Comment: Not that I am a big fan of implicit user-defined conversioned. I wouldn't ever want to implicitly convert string to bool as in my example.

But sometimes they are useful. Take std::string(const char*) for example.

Comment: @shura: `std::string(const char*)` and `if(my_stream)` are the only two examples of  useful implicit conversions that I see repeated over and over. (And I consider both debatable.) Has anyone ever come up with another useful example?

Comment: @sbi In Unreal C++ they have their own string class `FString` and `FText` on top of there being `const char*` and `std::string`. The only way to cast `std::string` to `FString` is to chain cast via `const char*` every time. Implicit cast here would be handy.

Comment: @AustinWBryan That would seem this way, but every time I thought so (I haven't done this in more than a decade), it turned out they caused problems.

Answer (score -3):

There's a group of operators that have to be overloaded as non-static member functions: assignment, subscripting, function call, class member access, conversion functions.

I guess the standard's committee or Stroustrup simply felt it might be just too confusing if it was allowed to inject these very special behaviors to classes from outside.

---

I suppose the best way to get the answer would be to e-mail the author.

Comment: Um, wasn't this decided long before the standards committee ever met for the first time?

Comment: Or perhaps Stroustrup felt this way. This is merely a speculation. What do these all have in common, so they all have to be members? I don't see any technical reason, why they should (OK, assignment would have a technical problem, since the compiler would otherwise synthesize it).

Comment: sad because converting "from std::string" to other things is a common desire