# Are implicit conversions good or bad in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

In [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3830.pdf):

> N3830 Scoped Resource - Generic RAII Wrapper for the Standard Library

a `scoped_resource` RAII wrapper is presented.

On page 4, there is some code like this:

> ```
> auto hFile = std::make_scoped_resource(
>       ...
>     );    
> ...
>
> // cast operator makes it seamless to use with other APIs needing a HANDLE
> ReadFile(hFile, ...);
> ```

The Win32 API [`ReadFile()` takes a *raw* `HANDLE` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), instead `hFile` is an instance of `scoped_resource`, so to make the above code work, there is an *implicit* cast operator implemented by `scoped_resource`.

But, wasn't the "modern" recommendation to avoid these kind of *implicit* conversions?

For example, ATL/MFC `CString` has an *implicit* conversion (cast operator) to `LPCTSTR` (`const char/wchar_t*`, i.e. a raw C-string pointer), instead STL strings have an *explicit* `c_str()` method.

Similarly, smart pointers like `unique_ptr` have an *explicit* `get()` method to access the underlying wrapped pointer; and that recommendation against implicit conversion seems also present in this blog post:

> [Reader Q&A: Why don’t modern smart pointers implicitly convert to *?](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/)

So, are these implicit conversions (like ATL/MFC `CString` and the newly proposed `scoped_resource`) good or not for modern C++?

From a coding perspective, I'd say that being able to simply directly pass a RAII wrapper - be it `CString` or `scoped_resource` - to a C API expecting a "raw" parameter (like a raw C string pointer, or raw handle), relying on *implicit* conversions, and without calling some `.GetString()`/`.get()` method, seems very convenient.

Comment: Certainly any kind of ownership transfer must never be implicit. (cough `auto_ptr` cough)

Comment: Implicit conversions can cause tons of trouble, and I don't think the 'overhead' of 6 characters for writing `.get()` is worth it.

Comment: @Xeo: So is the proposal of `scoped_resource` with the implicit conversion wrong?

Comment: @KerrekSB: We're not talking about ownership transfer, but just "observing" the wrapped "raw" thing.

Comment: I found 4 votes to close this question: this seems just ridicolous to me. Those who vote for closing this question should clarify the reasons why (assuming there are any _valid_). This question seems to me elaborated and well crafted. And if there is something that can be made to make it better, that can be inserted into comments.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Yeah, but that's also tricky. Suppose you have some smart pointer class `P` so that `P p(new T)` works. Now if `p` can be implicitly converted to `T*`, will `P q(p)` work? And `delete p`? So you have to be really careful even when you're just *near* ownership issues. Generally, passing by reference solves this because you use the familiar and concise `*p` syntax.

Comment: @KerrekSB: So is there a bug in `scoped_resource` proposal due to the _implicit_ raw handle conversion? (I noted that both STL strings and STL smart pointers have the **explicit** _"getter"_, be it `c_str()` or `get()`, instead that proposed RAII wrapper was different from this point of view.)

Comment: I think implicit conversions are good/convenient for the application programmer, but bad for library developers as they introduce complexity and other issues: A good example is the interplay between implicit conversion and template deduction.

From a library perspective, it is easier to constrain language features. For that, you could even say that library is easier to maintain if you remove some of the overloading and default parameters. It's less convenient for application programmers, but there is less ambiguity and complexity.
So, it's really a choice between convenience and simplicity.

Comment: @TingL: Thanks. I'd be happy to upvote your comment if it were posted in the answers section.

Comment: @Mr.C64: Don't know, I haven't read the proposal. Did it make it through the recent meeting?

Comment: @Mr.C64 I was trying to write an answer when the question was blocked minutes after being posted.

Answer (score 3):

Below is quote from [C++ Primer 5th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113).

> #### Caution: Avoid Overuse of Conversion Functions
>
> As with using overloaded operators, judicious use of conversion operators can
>   greatly simplify the job of a class designer and make using a class easier.
>   However, some conversions can be misleading. Conversion operators are
>   misleading when there is no obvious single mapping between the class type
>   and the conversion type.
>
> For example, consider a class that represents a Date. We might think it
>   would be a good idea to provide a conversion from `Date` to `int`. However,
>   what value should the conversion function return? The function might return
>   a decimal representation of the year, month, and day. For example, July 30, 1989 might be represented as the int value 19800730. Alternatively, the conversion operator might return an int representing the number of days that have elapsed since some epoch point, such as January 1, 1970. Both these conversions have the desirable property that later dates correspond to larger integers, and so either might be useful.
>
> The problem is that there is no single one-to-one mapping between an
>   object of type `Date` and a value of type `int`. In such cases, it is better not
>   to define the conversion operator. Instead, the class ought to define one or
>   more ordinary members to extract the information in these various forms.

So, what I can say is that in practice, classes should rarely provide conversion operators. Too often users are more likely to be surprised if a conversion happens automatically than to be helped by the
existence of the conversion. However, there is one important exception to this rule of
thumb: It is not uncommon for classes to define conversions to `bool`.
Under earlier versions of the standard, classes that wanted to define a conversion to
bool faced a problem: Because bool is an arithmetic type, a class-type object that is
converted to bool can be used in any context where an arithmetic type is expected.
Such conversions can happen in surprising ways. In particular, if `istream` had a
conversion to `bool`, the following code would compile:

```
int i = 42;
cin << i; // this code would be legal if the conversion to bool were not explicit!
```

You should use `explicit` conversion operators. Below is a little example:

```
class small_int 
{
private: 
  int val;
public:
  // constructors and other members
  explicit operator int() const { return this->val; }
}
```

... and in the program:

```
int main()
{
  SmallInt si = 3; // ok: the SmallInt constructor is not explicit
  si + 3; // error: implicit is conversion required, but operator int is explicit
  static_cast<int>(si) + 3; // ok: explicitly request the conversion

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think just `int(si)` is a better fit for the conversion.

Comment: Does the book actually use `19800730` as example for a date with year *1989*?

Answer (score 1):

I think implicit conversions are good/convenient for the application programmer, but bad for library developers as they introduce complexity and other issues: A good example is the interplay between implicit conversion and template deduction.

From a library perspective, it is easier to constrain language features to a minimal set. For that, you could even say that library is easier to maintain if you remove some of the overloading and default parameters. It's less convenient for application programmers, but there is less ambiguity and complexity.

So, it's really a choice between convenience and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on exact conversion type, but, in general, there are some areas where implicit conversions may introduce problems, whereas explicit rather may not.

Generally, doing anything explicitly in programming is a more safe way.

There is a good source of information on [C++ in general](http://en.cppreference.com/) and on [implicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) and [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) conversions in particular.