# What does operator <- do in c++?

Tags: c++, operators

Reading really long functions can be very fun!

```
int crazylongfun()
{
  int x = -1;
  foo b = -42;

//... 1000 lines below

  if( b<-x)
  {
    std::printf("How did I get here there is no left arrow operator?\n");
  }

  return 0;    
}
```

Looking at foo definition

```
struct foo
{
  int  x;

  foo(int a) : x(a) {}

  operator int() const
  {
    return x;
  }
};
```

This compiles just fine and produces the desired output. What is the mechanism that allows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably implicit conversion operators in c++ are controversial, e.g. [Are implicit conversions good or bad in modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160432/are-implicit-conversions-good-or-bad-in-modern-c). When they are defined there can be very interesting syntactical situations to the unaware programmer. The above is just an example.

Here is how this works:

Struct foo has a conversion operator defined and therefore it is convertible to int which causes it to be implicitly converted and compared to the local variable x for less than minus x.

The code is actually:

```
if(int(b)<(-x))
```

i.e. There is no left arrow operator <- in c++ .

Answer (score 5):

It's simply, "less than negative X".

```
if (b < -x)
```

After 1,000 lines I'd be kinda cross-eyed, too!

Answer (score 3):

> What does operator `<-` do in c++?

It's actually not an operator (in contrast to `->`, which is one).

As mentioned in the other answers, there are in fact two operator functions applied:

1. Unary `operator-()` applying a negative sign to the value
2. Less comparison `operator<()`